# Connect rosccp with graphics

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was wondering if I could connect ros C++ with graphics. For example, if I want to draw a map from my lidar data (I know about gmapping, but I want to create something on my own), is there a library or generally a tool that can help me with that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241132/connect-rosccp-with-graphics/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) is the canonical tool for displaying data in ROS; it has built-in plugins for maps, transforms, most types of sensors, and a fair number of other things. It also handles TF and displays the relative position of different data sources with respect to each other in 3D.

ROS doesn't provide any other C++ libraries for displaying graphics or interacting with images; there are already lots of good C++ libraries for doing these things if you want to integrate that functionality directly into your program.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0